# AngularJS with Laravel 5 using NPM

Tags: angularjs, npm, laravel-5

I want to use `AngularJS` with `Laravel 5`. Since Laravel uses NPM to get `gulp` and `laravel-elixir`, my first step was to edit `packages.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "laravel-elixir": "*",
    "angular": "*" // import angular
  }
}
```

After executing `npm install` AngularJS is downloaded to the `node_modules/angular` folder.

Now how do I use `angular.js` in my HTML?

**NOTE:** My host settings are pointing to a `public` folder.

**EDIT:**
For now I'm using this piece of code in my `gulp.js` file:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy('node_modules/angular/*.min.js', 'public/js/');
    mix.copy('node_modules/angular-aria/*.min.js', 'public/js/');
    mix.copy('node_modules/angular-animate/*.min.js', 'public/js/');
});
```

Comment: You need to use something like browserify to require angular in the client or just include in your html the path to angular.js

Comment: @JsIsAwesome simply including is not possible, since `node_modules` folder is not accessible from `public` folder. I've edited my question to include a simpler solution, which doesn't require additional packages. But I'm curious if there is a better way to go, then just copying files.

Comment: As i say if you want to use npm packages in the client side you need to use browserify and then require the packages, if not then just use bower and add the files to your index.html like all scripts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I did, what I should've done before asking this question. [Documentation.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir)

As an example I will try to use [LumX CSS framework](http://ui.lumapps.com/) bower package with Laravel 5.

**Step 1. Install LumX and required packages.**

Be sure you have [Bower](http://bower.io/) installed. Execute `bower install lumx`, this will create `bower_components` folder within Laravel directory. You may want to add this directory to `.gitignore`.

**Step 2. Prepare your project files.**

Create `resources/assets/sass` folder and `app.scss`:

```
@import "../../../bower_components/mdi/scss/materialdesignicons";
@import "../../../bower_components/lumx/dist/scss/lumx";
```

Create `resources/assets/js` folder and `app.js`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['lumx']);
```

Also be sure, that you have `public/js`, `public/css`, `public/fonts` folders and they are writable.

**Step 3. Use gulp.**

Edit your `gulpfile.js` file:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
        .scripts([
            // Combine all js files into one.
            // Path is relative to resource/js folder.
            '../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            '../../bower_components/velocity/velocity.min.js',
            '../../bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js',
            '../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
            '../../bower_components/lumx/dist/lumx.min.js',
        ], 'public/js/app.js')
        // Since css file will be place into public/css folder,
        // we need to copy font files too
        .copy('bower_components/mdi/fonts', 'public/fonts');
});
```

And execute `gulp` command.

**Step 4. Use CSS and JS files.**

Insert this into `head` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
```

Insert this before closing `body tag:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Specify `ng-app` attribute:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="deup">
```